# PayPal Error while Make Payment Using card 10752 error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox

When you make payment using PayPal card and get an error message something like

> ErrorCode: 10752 Message: This transaction can not be processed.

Comment: While [self-answering is encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), your question does need to be on-topic. Here, apart from lacking enough detail, your question also appears to be a duplicate of [How to config paypal credit card in YII framework](//stackoverflow.com/q/31579600)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Please check phone number is available or not in your amount receiving sandbox PayPal account.